# beginners issue with using of lists in python

Tags: python, list, replace

This is a **list**

```
['lady']    
['hen']
['horse']
```

I need to remove `"[","'","]"`

and look like

```
lady
hen
horse
```

I can't use indices because each words have different length, I know I want to change using replace function. Can you help?

Comment: It seems like you have 3 lists there, do you mean `['lady', 'hen', 'horse']`

Comment: @joe no its like  ['lady'],['hen']['horse'] to lady horse hen

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking. Are those individual lists with one string in them or are they part of a larger list containing all 3?

Comment: Do you have a list like this `[['lady'],['hen'],['horse']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip your elements with [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) method :

```
>>> l =["['lady']", "['hen']", "['horse']"]
>>> [i.strip("'][") for i in l]
['lady', 'hen', 'horse']
```

Comment: @hanish how did you end up with a list like that in the first place?

Comment: @paul i need to extract text from a file those are the not the exact word i have to extract obviously, its a big list and split it and end up like this hmmm

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you might have nested lists.

Is this what you are after?

```
>>>animals = ["lady", "hen", "horse"]
>>>for i in animals:
...  print i 
lady
hen
horse
```

you can use list comprehension:

```
>>>animalsnested = [['pig'], ['cat'], ['dog']]
>>>animals = [i for x in animals for i in x]
>>>animals
['pig', 'cat', 'dog']
```